# Merge two github accounts

Tags: github

Is it possible to merge two GitHub accounts into one?
I had one work account but would like to merge into a personal one.

I found some details about transferring ownership of the own repos which will merge all commit history etc.
Could anyone please confirm if it will transfer all commit history for any contributions made to another third party repos?

What will happen in the third party repos where I have made contributions from work account after the work account is deleted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I logged a support ticket with github and below is the summary:

After deleting work account and following steps as mentioned https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/creating-and-managing-repositories/transferring-a-repository did not bring contributions across to the personal account.

As work account was deleted - it started showing as a ghost account.
The commits made through work account were as from the personal acccount but contribution history (PR or any reviews) didn't come across to the personal account.

So make sure you think of above steps before removing any of your Github account.

**Below were responses from Github:**

As pull requests, issues and all activity in the GitHub web UI excluding commits are directly tied to the account that created them, they will not be counted on the new account even if you add the old account's email address to the new account.

Pull requests are replaced with the ghost user when the account is deleted. On the other hand, we read the email address from the metadata stored inside a commit and attempt to match commits up with a user account, so those that meet the contribution criteria will be counted on the new account.

Answer (score 1):

That is what describes "[Merging multiple personal accounts](https://docs.github.com/en/account-and-profile/setting-up-and-managing-your-personal-account-on-github/managing-your-personal-account/merging-multiple-personal-accounts)"

And its [repository transfer](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/creating-and-managing-repositories/transferring-a-repository) process (from the account you want to delete to the account you want to keep) should transfer issues, pull requests, and wikis.

You will need to add the email address you used to author the commits (of the old account) to the account you're keeping.
That way, your old contributions will be preserved.

Comment: VonC  When I transferred all local repos etc that looks straightforward. My main question is what will happen to the contributions I have made through the work account. These repos are not in my account. I am a collaborator for these external repos through work email address.

Comment: @mk22 That is what "You will need to add the email address you used to author the commits (of the old account) to the account you're keeping." is for. If you [add your old account work email](https://docs.github.com/en/account-and-profile/setting-up-and-managing-your-personal-account-on-github/managing-email-preferences/adding-an-email-address-to-your-github-account) to your personal account, the contribution should be preserved.

Comment: @Vanc so I have followed all steps (deleted account with work email address) and added work email address to personal email address github account. And I can see still old usersname link is displayed on the contributed repos which takes to 404 page. Also I couldn't see any contributions transferred to my personal github profile.

Comment: Not sure if this will sync after sometime but it hasn't transferred the contributions :(

Comment: @mk22 I do not know if there is a synchronization delay indeed. But if after a day or two, nothing changes, don't hesitate to submit your case to [GitHub support](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions), a bit like [this ticket](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/35393).

Comment: My deleted work account now shows as ghost account on work repos. Can anyone help how can I make it display as personal account. Also none of contributions from work account (which is now deleted) is displaying on the personal account.

Comment: @mk22 That would be a query to address to GitHub support.

Comment: So I figured out its not possible to transfer contributions from one account to another account. It does update commits as from teh personal account but didn't transfer all PR -> contribitions or work done to the personal account.